# Multiple asynchronous function calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

given the situation there is an action inside a NodeJs server (in my case SailsJs) where I need to create x different entities in one call. It is not possible for the client to call the action x times. 
What is the best/recommended way of creating these entities regarding callbacks. If I understood callbacks right it is not possibile to just built something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
  User.create(...).exec(...);
}
```

What would be the right way to implement this?

Bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy do it with [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#times) package

```
var async = require('async');
async.times(x, function(n, next){
    User.create(...).exec(function(err, user) {
      next(err, user)
    })
}, function(err, users) {
  // processed x times 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hand over an array of to be created users to `User.create`. You prepare the array of users first.

With lots of users to be created having some many-to-many relationships, native calls are much faster, e.g. Mongo bulk inserts.

[Sails Reference regarding create](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create)

Comment: Completely agree! I think sails docs acknowledges that waterline is perfect for quick and simple operations but you definitely should use .query if you need to.Much better to utilise native DB where it can perform operations in a more efficient manner. Bulk insert is a prime example.